# How can I get HTML5 video tag with multiple source tags with codec specification working on Firefox?

Tags: html, cross-browser, html5-video

I receive mp4 videos where the video stream codec is H.265 HEVC. The newer iOS devices record in this format and only Safari and mobile Safari can play it back right now, however the majority of the world does not have Apple devices, even in the bubble of the US. So I re-encode these videos into the (now) widely accepted H.264 so I can serve them for Firefox, Chrome and other non Apple browsers.

However since I already have the HEVC version, which does provide a better compression/quality than H.264, I'd want to serve that together with the H.264 so the viewer device can choose which one it gonna pick. This is kind of like the `srcset` for `img`.

The good news is that there is way to do that: instead of

```
<video controls src="h264.mp4"></video>
```

I can have

```
<video controls>
  <source src="h264.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1">
  <source src="hevc.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=hevc">
</video>
```

The bad news is that this works with Linux Chromium stable and beta, Windows Chromium, Edge. But Firefox trips both on Linux and Windows. How can I fix this? I must include codec information because both files are mp4.

Comment: Note: the `<source>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob that's right, it's like that in my source code. I'll change it in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With trial and error I figured out that Firefox accepts the codec string if I not only specify `avc1` but I also fully specify the profile and the level with a specific 6 digit hexadecimal code, for example:

`type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.64001E"`

It's another question how someone can come across that hexadecimal code, for details look at [How can I (or is it possible to) convert the AVC codec profile and level to the MIME codec definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891176/how-can-i-or-is-it-possible-to-convert-the-avc-codec-profile-and-level-to-the/59895203#59895203) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#AVC_profiles

Comment: One warning here: I unintentionally used `type="video/mp4; codecs='avc1.64001E'"` notation (which allows additional audio codec specification after a comma), it has extra apostrophes. But this dumbfounded Firefox and Chrome. Insanity. So you want to leave out the apostrophe.