# How can I (or is it possible to) convert the AVC codec profile and level to the MIME codec definition?

Tags: html5-video, mp4, codec, ffprobe, mediainfo

In my use-case I have to provide codec specification within the HTML5 `video` `source`'s MIME type. But even a `type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1"` is not detailed enough for Firefox. Firefox needs the extra detail of for example `type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.64001E"`. My problem is that I don't know where to get this `64001E` part from.

The whole identification happens on server side. So far I was using `ffprobe` and that's perfectly supplies me JSON format output, like so:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v:0 -v info -of json -show_entries stream=codec_name,level,profile,width,height -i 1CE89B23-F9BD-43B9-805B-C49ACA9E5FFB_xxxxxxx.mp4 
    "streams": [
        {
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "profile": "High",
            "width": 1080,
            "height": 1920,
            "level": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

I can get the profile and the level, but nothing like `64001E`. In my local environment I also have `mediainfo`:

```
mediainfo 8038B652-106B-4FBB-BAD6-AF7E32913FDE_xxxxxxx.mp4 
General
Complete name                            : 8038B652-106B-4FBB-BAD6-AF7E32913FDE_xxxxxxx.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 1.18 MiB
Duration                                 : 6 s 634 ms
Overall bit rate                         : 1 496 kb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf57.83.100

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3
Format settings                          : CABAC / 5 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 5 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 6 s 634 ms
Bit rate                                 : 1 396 kb/s
Width                                    : 360 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 0.750
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 30.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.269
Stream size                              : 1.10 MiB (93%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 152 r2854 e9a5903
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=5 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=8 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=15 / lookahead_threads=2 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=1 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=25 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=50 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=17.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 6 s 632 ms
Duration_LastFrame                       : -9 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 90.4 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel layout                           : C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 43.066 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 73.2 KiB (6%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

What we see here is that the AAC part has a longer Codec ID `mp4a-40-2`, but the video stream is still just `avc1`.

I'm looking at lists https://tools.woolyss.com/html5-canplaytype-tester/ and https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Video_type_parameters and I think maybe there's a programmatic way to convert the codec profile + level to the code what the MIME type codec specification has.

---

In https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter I see that `"avc1.4d002a"` means `Main Profile, Level 4.2`. Looking at the list I linked earlier I figured that the 6 hex digits can be broken down into groups of two. The last two is the level. In this latest example the Level is `4.2`, we just have to remove the dot => it becomes `42`, which is `2a` hex. The other 4 hex digits are related to the profile as Main, High, etc and then Progressive, but I haven't found a definition yet, and I wonder if the `ffprobe` is able to output things like `High 4:2:2 Intra Level` or `High Progressive Level`. We'll see.

---

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6381#page-12 has some examples, but I followed the links and still don't see any definitive list or anything.

---

The ITU-T H.264 specification Annex A lists 14 profiles. In those listings there's a `profile_idc` mentioned, which seems to be the decimal for the first two hex digits, for example `High`'s `profile_idc` is 100 decimal, which is 64 hexa. Now we just need to figure out the middle two hexa digits. Preferably a GitHub repo source file would be great where these things are curated into a sane concise const literal array.

Comment: It is described in e.g. Mozilla link ("PPCCLL is six hexadecimal digits specifying the profile number (PP), constraint set flags (CC), and level (LL)"). If you don't find a tool fitting your needs (extracting also CC), we could extend e.g. MediaInfo for that, [let us know](https://mediaarea.net/Services).

Comment: @JérômeMartinez Oh, it's right here in there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#AVC_profiles

Comment: @JérômeMartinez if you phrase that in an answer with that latest anchor link I can mark your answer. I don't think `ffprobe` can output this, but I can transform it from the level and the profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is described in e.g. [Mozilla link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#AVC_profiles) ("PPCCLL is six hexadecimal digits specifying the profile number (PP), constraint set flags (CC), and level (LL)"). If you don't find a tool fitting your needs, we could extend e.g. MediaInfo for that, [let us know](https://mediaarea.net/Services).
Note: the CC indicated in the list are the expected flags, not the ones really in the file, it should be OK 99.99% of the time but you can not be sure it is the real content. MediaInfo internally reads the flags but it does not export them for the moment.

Comment: Deep link to Mozilla's list of AVC profiles and corresponding codes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/codecs_parameter#AVC_profiles